# JSF 'Tab' bean scope

Tags: ajax, jsf, myfaces, conversation-scope, orchestra

I need create webapp with two pages and one backing bean for both pages. I tried `@SessionScoped`, but when I open other tab in a browser, I see the same data as in previous tab.

I tried to use `MyFaces Orchestra`, but backing bean is created on each AJAX request.

How to solve the problem?

Beforehand thankfull, Ilya

Comment: Does it absolutely have to be 2 pages? Is it possible to make it just 1 page with conditionally rendering of "results" or whatever? Then you can just use the standard JSF `@ViewScoped` for this. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope

Answer (score -1):

In a web browser if you open a new tab it will pass along the same session related cookies thus will be opend in the same session context. You need to open a new winodow to get a new session.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Please explain it.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the concrete question at all. Fatfreddy, the OP is asking how to limit the bean scope to the interaction between 2 pages in the same browser tab, exactly like as CDI's `@ConversationScoped` is doing.

Comment: Sorry my bad :) I didin't get the root of the problem :)